# Line series solve nearest from screen does not return appropriate values

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChart JS with a line series and I am subscribing to the mousedrag event on the series, this in turn returns the coordinates of the starting point. When I run the `solveNearestFromScreen` on the point it returns point with the closest y value(As per my observation). I would like to obtain the point which is nearest in distance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point returned by the [`solveNearestFromScreen`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/lineseries.html#solvenearestfromscreen) method depends on the used [`DataPattern`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/globals.html#datapatterns). If you are using `DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive`, `DataPatterns.horizontalRegressive`, `DataPatterns.verticalProgessive` or `DataPatterns.verticalRegressive` data pattern the point returned by `solveNearestFromScreen` is based only on single axis value. If the series is using `DataPatterns.freeForm` (which is default) the returned point will be the closest data point.

HorizontalProgressive pattern solve nearest:

[image: Progressive pattern solve]

FreeForm pattern solve nearest:

[image: FreeForm solve]

Also there is a [`solveNearest`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#solvenearest) method on `ChartXY` that can be used to solve nearest from multiple axes.

When using the `solveNearest` or `solveNearestFromScreen` methods, it's important to convert the mouse position to engine coordinate space before solving. This can be done with [`chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(event.clientX, event.clientY)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/interfaces/publicengine.html#clientlocation2engine). That method will convert the given mouse coordinate to a point in the engine coordinates which can then be used to solve the nearest point.

```js
const marker = chart.addChartMarkerXY()
chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDrag((obj, ev)=>{
    const m = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(ev.clientX,ev.clientY)
    marker.setPosition(chart.solveNearest(m).location)
})
```

See below for a full code example for moving a marker to a nearest point when mouse is dragged on the series area.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidLine,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    UIOrigins,
    DataPatterns
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const diesel = [
    { x: 0, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 1, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 2, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 3, y: 1.58 },
    { x: 4, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 5, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 6, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 7, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 8, y: 2.26 },
    { x: 9, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 10, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 11, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 12, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 13, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 14, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 15, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 16, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 17, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 18, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 19, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 20, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 21, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 22, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 23, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 24, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 25, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 27, y: 1.5 },
    { x: 28, y: 1.5 },
    { x: 29, y: 1.5 }
]

const gasoline = [
    { x: 0, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 1, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 2, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 3, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 4, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 5, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 6, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 7, y: 1.92 },
    { x: 8, y: 1.50 },
    { x: 9, y: 1.50 },
    { x: 10, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 11, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 12, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 13, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 14, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 15, y: 1.32 },
    { x: 16, y: 1.40 },
    { x: 17, y: 1.44 },
    { x: 18, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 19, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 20, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 21, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 22, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 23, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 24, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 25, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 27, y: 1.30 },
    { x: 28, y: 1.30 },
    { x: 29, y: 1.30 }
]

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries()

const lineSeries2 = chart.addLineSeries()

lineSeries2.add(diesel.map((point) => ({ x: point.x, y: point.y })))
lineSeries.add(gasoline.map((point) => ({ x: point.x, y: point.y })))
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setInterval(0, 3, false, true)
chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleZoom(false)
chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleFit(false)

const marker = chart.addChartMarkerXY()

// Add Chart to LegendBox.
chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDrag((obj, ev)=>{
    const m = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(ev.clientX,ev.clientY)
    marker.setPosition(chart.solveNearest(m).location)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```